# ADT Android Emulator - Cordova app has no internet access but the emulator does

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I'm working on an Android app using Cordova.  When emulating, the emulator has internet access.  I can browse the web with no problems.)  The issue is that my app itself has no internet access.  The app needs to call a number of web services that will return JSON data and all the calls fail.  I specifically check in the app for connectivity and all checks fail.

To be clear, the emulator has connectivity.  It is only my app that does not.

Is there a setting in Eclipse or in the app itself that needs to be changed?

Comment: added internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is already there.

Comment: How do you "check for connectivity"?

Comment: I'm using Cordova to build a web app (I should update my question as this seems like relevant information.)  I check connectivity using online = window.navigator.onLine.  If I remove this check and simply try to access the necessary web services, they all fail.

Comment: Did you add those websites to your whitelist so that Cordova/phonegap doesn't block them? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: I have already added the necessary sites to the whitelist. To make matter even more strange, the app builds and runs perfectly off of a colleagues machine.  When he puts it on an Android device, it works.  When I try, it fails.